# prove that the ternary cantor set is compact and a perfect set.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, cantor-set

prove that the ternary cantor set is compact and a perfect set.

**My trial:**

I know that I should prove that it is closed and bounded, for proving that it is closed because finite union of closed sets (the cantor set definition is this ) are closed  and also using that arbitrary intersection of closed sets are closed.

Now to prove that it is bounded shall I prove that its lenght is zero?

How can I prove that it has no isolated points?

Comment: It's contained in the unit interval.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thank you .... so I will edit my question to another one

Comment: On a side note, I don't see how being finite union of closed sets is contained in the definition (I mean, it is apparent that it is union of *one* closed set, and thus of *finitely many* closed sets, but I would guess that's not what you're referring to)

Comment: each interval is a finite union of closed intervals and hence closed @SaucyO'Path

Comment: @hopefully Ah, ok. I was misreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$C_n=\frac{C_{n-1}}{3}\cup \left(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{C_{n-1}}{3}\right)$ with $C_0=[0,1]$.

- $C_n$ is closed
- $C_n$ is contained in $[0,1]$
- Every interval in $C_n$ is at maximum $(\frac{1}{3})^n$ in length

Cantor set is defined as:

$C:=\cap_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n$

By definition it is clear that

- it is bounded (is contained in $[0,1]$)
- it is closed (is the **infinite** intersection of closed sets)
- Every neighborhood of a point in $C$ must contain another point of $C$at least: you can prove it using the third property of $C_n$

Note that this property is noteworthy, since the set is totally disconnected

**Rigorous proof:**
By simple computations, you can note that the Cantor set consists of all the real numbers of the unit interval that do not require 1 in their [ternary expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system?wprov=sfla1). Thus, for every $c\in C=0.c_1c_2\dots$, there exists, for all $n$, a number $c_n \in C$ such that $|c-c_n|<3^{-n}$, constructed in this way: truncate $c$ to the $n+1$-th digit, and substitute it with $2$ if it is $0$ and viceversa. The number so constructed is still in $C$, and has a distance from $c$ of $\frac{2}{3}\cdot 3^{-n}$.

Comment: could you please show me rigorously how to show that every point in the Cantor set is a cluster point?

Comment: @hopefully I inserted a proof, let me know if it is clear